# FinderSync context menu items beep, never call action

Tags: nsmenuitem, findersync

I want to generate a menu which will call functions on a class other than that one which generated the menu, and then place that in Finder. However, when I click the menu item, the system error beep plays and my function is never called.

Here's a SSCCE:

```swift
import Cocoa
import FinderSync



@objc(FinderSync)
class FinderSync: FIFinderSync {

    var observedFolder = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/")


    override init() {
        super.init()

        NSLog("\(FinderSync.self.className()) launched from \(Bundle.main.bundlePath)")

        // Set up the directory we are syncing.
        FIFinderSyncController.default().directoryURLs = [self.observedFolder]
    }



    // MARK: - Menu and toolbar item support

    override var toolbarItemName: String {
        return "Wonderful Test App"
    }


    override var toolbarItemToolTip: String {
        return "This is wonderful"
    }


    override var toolbarItemImage: NSImage {
        return NSImage(named: NSImage.cautionName)!
    }


    override func menu(for menuKind: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
        let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Click me!", action: #selector(SomeOtherClass.remoteAction), keyEquivalent: "")
        menuItem.target = SomeOtherClass.shared
        menuItem.action = #selector(SomeOtherClass.remoteAction)
        menu.addItem(menuItem)
        return menu
    }
}



@objc(SomeOtherClass)
public class SomeOtherClass: NSObject {

    public static let shared = SomeOtherClass()


    deinit {
        NSLog("Deallocated!")
        preconditionFailure("Shared instance should never be deallocated!")
    }


    @IBAction
    @objc(remoteAction:)
    public func remoteAction(_ sender: Any?) {
        NSLog("Remote!")
    }
}
```

I've verified via the memory debugger that `SomeOtherClass.shared` is still in memory before, during, and after the menu item is clicked, so it's not being deallocated or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can't add actions which are within any class other than your FinderSync extension's principal class. Which is about as stupid as everything else about `NSMenuItem`, so I'm not surprised.

So, you'll have to move the action(s) into your `FinderSync` class, despite how ugly that might be for organization.